# WSO2 Banking sample Carbon App: "Cannot add multiple dependencies with same identity"

Tags: esb, wso2, wso2-esb

Im trying out the banking sample application and when i try to add or select proxies im laning into an error as shown below: Please help

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like your are trying to include multiple dependencies with same name to your Carbon application project, please find my comment on Jira (https://wso2.org/jira/browse/TOOLS-1130)

Comment: Please find my last comment on Jira [link] (https://wso2.org/jira/browse/TOOLS-1130) I hope it's clear to you now

Answer (score 0):

Was able to add it by un checking the registry resources. Please find the attached screen shot of the Same

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Issue raised: https://wso2.org/jira/browse/TOOLS-1130